# What caused the explosion in Coopertown?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, messiah-complex

When Hope was born in the Messiah Complex, there was an explosion (referenced later on by a news presenter:

> At approximately 10:20pm last night, local residents were rocked by a series of explosions that some believed to be earthquakes.

There is an explosion on the previous page, but it doesn't have an obvious cause.

Was the destruction *just* caused by the conflict or did it have something to do with Hope's birth?